# Why does $2^q = 10^p$ follows from $log_{10}2$?

Tags: logarithms

In the solution to exercise 1.2.2, 10 in Knuth’s The Art of Computer Programming, he states

> If $log_{10}2 = \frac{p}{q}$, with $p$ and $q$ positive, then $2^q$ = $10^p$ (...)

Where does this relationship come from?

Comment: Do you know how to rewrite $\log_{10}2=x$ as an exponential equation? Do you know what $\log_{10}y=z$ means?

Comment: $log_{10}2 = \frac{p}{q} \iff 2=10^{\frac{p}{q}}$

Comment: Apply the base 10 exponential to both sides of the equality and then raise to the power $q$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I know that i could rewrite it as $2 = 10^x$, but that does not help me to understand this.

Comment: Sure it does. What if you do the same thing with $\log_{10}2=p/q$?

Comment: @PierreCarre and Gerry Myerson Thank you to both of you, now I get it.

Answer (score 3):

With the help of PrierreCarre and Gerry Myerson:

$
log_{10}2 = \frac{p}{q} \\
\Leftrightarrow 2 = 10^\frac{p}{q} \\
\Leftrightarrow 2^q = 10^p
$